# Creating table with DISTSTYLE ALL in Pentaho Data Integration throws error on compatibility over DISTKEY

Tags: amazon-redshift, pentaho-spoon

> Amazon Invalid operation: DISTSTYLE EVEN/ALL/NONE is not compatible with a DISTKEY;
>
> ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : Error initializing step
>
> ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : Step failed to initialize!

Comment: It say there is syntax problem in your query, you may be creating a table incorrect syntax, as far as I understand, this error has nothing to do with `pantaho`, try running your create table using command, it will throw same error.

Comment: you set a distkey AND a diststyle (of  EVEN/ALL/NONE) this is not possible. remove the distkey or diststyle

Comment: Including create table statement would be helpful for us to see where the problem is. Like Jon Scott said if you have both `DISTKEY` and `DISTSTYLE` use now of them

Comment: Thanks @JonScott 
It worked. So Basically we don't need distribution KEY as we are inserting every row to every node.